# User input in swift toInt() returning nil

Tags: swift, null

i'm trying to create a simple user input but the only function that i have found in swift is this one

```
func input() -> String {
    var keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    var inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String!
}
```

then i'm trying to convert input() to an Int for a mathematic operation (i'm using 1 as the input) with this

```
var inputToInt = input().toInt()!
```

in this point i get only nil i don't know what to do.

Comment: it will return nil only if your input() is nil. make sure of it. where are you taking 1 as input?

Comment: Most probably the reason is that the string contains a trailing newline character.

Comment: i'm doing this after defining the function println("Introduce a number") then var inputToInt = input().toInt()!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 2.0 has a function called `readLine()` - using it is a much better idea than rolling your own.

http://swiftdoc.org/swift-2/func/readLine/

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion to Int fails because the string contains newline. You can use this to clean it up:

```
let s = NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String!
if s.hasSuffix("\n") {
    return s.substringToIndex(x.endIndex.predecessor())
} else {
    return s
}
```